# ngCordova: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I created an ionic based calender example from [Raymond Camden's Blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/09/18/integrating-the-calendar-into-your-ionic-app) and from his [GitHub](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/calendarionic).

If I deploy the same example on my android device I get always the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined` in the console of Google Chrome. The [Plunker Code](http://embed.plnkr.co/NGStmNQY0CaibmJQlTo1/preview) and [git repo](https://github.com/ramogundogdu/ionCalendar)

[image]

Is the error based on the new version of ngCordova or samething else?

Comment: can you make a plnkr ?

Comment: here is the [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/NGStmNQY0CaibmJQlTo1/preview)

Comment: your plunker is all broken and links are all wrong ?! do you have a github repo maybe with it ?

Comment: Yes, I created a [git repo](https://github.com/ramogundogdu/ionCalendar)

Answer (score 1):

Cordova Plugins only works with real device.they  not works on browsers.So 
Use this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

//embed Code here 

});
```

Comment: I've added the controller code `MainCtrl` between `{//embed Code here}` and installed tha app on the device. The error in the browser indeed disappeared, but the Calander doesn't work anyway.